# Data Source in connection string - Setup project

Tags: c#

I'm creating a setup project for my C# desktop application.
What the data source should be written in the connection string for the access database ?and where I should put my database file in the solution project ?

Comment: mssql, ms access, mysql?

Comment: It looks like the database type is "MS Access".  Lotus 90, please clarify.

Comment: @Nate MS- Access Database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the VS setup project, you need to add the access database file as content and place it in the application directory, for example. To specify the location in the configuration file, you need to write a custom action that modifies the connection string accordingly. 
The following example is an installer class that sets the connection string after install phase (not tested):

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class Installer1 : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public Installer1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(Installer1_AfterInstall);
    }

    void Installer1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        string sTargetDir = Context.Parameters["TargetDir"];
        string sAppConfig = Path.Combine(sTargetDir, "<your app>.exe.config");
        string sDBPath = Path.Combine(sTargetDir, "<your db>.mdb");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sAppConfig);
        var elem = doc.Root.Element("/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='<your connection name>']");
        string connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};", sDBPath);
        elem.SetAttributeValue("connectionString", connectionString);
        doc.Save(sAppConfig);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Wix`](http://wixtoolset.org/) which has the `XmlFile` utility in the `util` extension which does it for you without you writing a custom action.